# Noremap failing when it comes to <esc>

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

When I `noremap` my <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, it breaks other things even though I'm not pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and those other mappings are also `noremap`.

I start with this vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
inoremap <silent> <Up> <esc><Up>
inoremap <silent> <Down> <esc><Down>
```

which lets me use the up and down arrows to escape.  Everything works fine with just the above. And I'm trying to break my <kbd>Esc</kbd>-pushing habit so I added:

```
inoremap <esc> <nop>
```

But now when I hit my up arrow in insert mode it simply inserts `0A` and down it inserts `0B` and leaves me in insert mode.  How could this mapping cause this problem when I'm not even when I'm not pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and everything is set to `noremap`?

Comment: Press Ctrl-V and then Up, you'll find Up itself is a composite key code, starting with Esc.

Comment: @muru My Ctrl-V results are slightly different ^[0A vs ^[[A, but the takeaway is the same since the ^[ which I recognize as a shortcut for escape is actually the actual composite key code of escape (Ctrl-V esc produces ^[ ).  Fortunately for me I only wanted this temporarily to break my habit, so I guess I'll live without this remap.  Thanks for your help, that did answer my question even if not the results I was hoping for.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] Dan!